# Threads: How to interrupt a thread from outside of that thread

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, interrupt

I have a simple GUI in which there are two buttons: `Print` and `Stop`.

When the user presses `print`, an already saved number is *printed continuously in a loop*.

When the user presses `Stop`, *the printing stops*.

*I am handling the printing of the number in a separate thread, because I need the thread to sleep for a millisecond before printing again.*

```
printBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                Thread a= new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        textArea.setText("");
                        for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
                            int result= 0;
                            System.out.println(result+"\n"); 
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } 
                        }
                    }
                });
                a.start();
            }
        });
```

*Now in the ActionListener of the Stop button, I want the first thread to be interrupted or stopped.* **How can I do that, since it needs to be interrupted from another thread?**

Comment: why from another thread?

Comment: Use a `Timer` or, better, a `ScheduledExectuorService`. Call `cancel()` on the `Timer` or `cancel()` on the `ScheduledFututre`. Don't use raw `Thread` unless you know what you are doing and have good reason to.

Comment: @ZerO Because this thread just includes whatever is inside the run method of this thread. That is a completely different button with a different action listener. Can I implement the action listener of that button inside this thread? Am I missing something here?

Comment: I am not sure if I got this wrong maybe. Why you not declare your thread as global. And then you call nameOfYourThread.interrupt(); in your second action listener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your first thread contains no Thread-blocking operation, you could for example check for a flag in the `for`-loop which gets set to `true` when you press the "Stop"-button.

```
public class WriterThread implements Runnable {

    private volatile boolean stopped = false;

    public synchronized void stop() {
        this.stopped = true;
    }

    public void run(){
            textArea.setText("");

            for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                    if (this.stopped) {
                            break;
                    }

                    int result= 0;
                    System.out.println(result+"\n");

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `stopped` should be declared `volatile`. If not, JIT will propably optimize the `if` statement (strip out).

Comment: Right, I mixed that up.

Answer (score 1):

Use `AtomicBoolean` as flag. It will ensure the thread safety.

```
Runnable r= new Runnable(){

    private AtomicBoolean stop= new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public void run(){
        for(...){

           if(stop.get()){
               break; // break the loop
           }

           ...

        }
    }

    public stop(){
        stop.set(true);
    }
}

Thread a= new Thread(r);
a.start();
r.stop();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final Thread a= new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        try {
            textArea.setText("");
            for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
                int result= 0;
                System.out.println(result+"\n"); 
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // ignore
        } 
    }
});

printBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        a.start();
    }
});

stopBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

       if( a.isAlive() ) {   
           a.interrupt();
       }
    }
});
```